# ngTouch fast click not working on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app, angularjs-ng-touch

I'm creating an iOS web app with AngularJS 1.2.10 and use ngTouch to achieve fast click functionality. However it does not seem to work. There is still a noticable delay when using ng-click.

As a test I removed ngTouch and added the fastclick.js library and this seems to work as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that including jQuery seems to break ngTouch on Angular 1.2.9 (I've not tested it on 1.2.10). My solution was to remove jQuery (which in my case wasn't too painful, as I don't include any plugins that depended on it).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Michal. However I'm not using jQuery.